# Escape encode file paths in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there anyway to automatically escape encode file paths copied to the clipboard by rightlicling the file and selecting file path to clipboard? [i.e. to turn `/` in the file path to `//`]. Asking because that would be useful for e.g. Python which requires filepaths to be escape encoded.

Comment: Do you mean `C:\1` to become `C:\\1`? But in almost all languages there are *raw* string literals allowing to use single ``\`` as a literal backslash. In Python, `C:\1` is `r'C:\1'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thanks! I guess i knew that, but for some reason wasn't thinking...

Comment: :) I do not know what kind of answer you actually are looking for. *Write your own plug-in*? The thing you want is not possible to do with just built-in features. If you want to find a regex that could help search and replace single backslashes, that is rather tedious and error prone. I have been trying to write a safe pattern for them, but there is no 100% bullet-proof version. If you want to just replace all ``\`` with ``\\`` there is no need of any regex at all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - on no, your first answer solved my problem :-) was just thanking you!

Comment: Ok, I posted that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to just use the same string as is but define it as a **raw/verbatim string literal**.

In raw string literals, backslashes are treated as literal backslashes, not as part of escape sequences like `\n` (newline) or `\r` (carriage return), etc.

Example to obtain `C:\1`:

- Python:  `r'C:\1'`
- C#: `@"C:\1"`